# How to execute a function after 1minute of the app goes to the background in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to execute a function and changing state along with navigation change when the app goes to the background after 1 minute of it in react native, i have used my code but it does not working..

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let timeoutId;
        const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
            // nextAppState can be 'active', 'background', or 'inactive'
            if (nextAppState === 'background') {
                // Your app is transitioning to the background
                console.log('App is in the background');
                isBackgndRef.current = true
       
                timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                    checkCondition();
                }, 20000);
                // You can perform any background-related tasks here
            } else if (nextAppState === 'active') {
                // Your app is transitioning to the foreground
                console.log('App is in the foreground');
                // You can perform any foreground-related tasks here
                if (isBackgndRef.current == true) {console.log("checking");
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                    isBackgndRef.current = false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Add the event listener when the component mounts
        AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
            clearTimeout(timeoutId); console.log("return called");
        };
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the background app state, please use setTimeout() from the
**react-native-background-timer** plugin instead of react-native setTimout().

Use the following link to find the react-native-background-timer plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer